# Name of mythical horse

Tags: animals, yajna

Sometime ago while reading one of the stories in a magazine, i came across a story narrating about a horse emerging out of a yagna, and is said to be blazing in fire and is currently under the oceans.

I am not sure of the magazine i came across and i am skeptical of the story that i read.

Is the story true by any means? If the story is true, is there a reference to the entire story and name of the horse.

Comment: [What's the meaning of these verses of 'The Horse' hymn in RigVeda?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17955/whats-the-meaning-of-these-verses-of-the-horse-hymn-in-rigveda)

Comment: If i remember correctly, this will be Kalki's horse.

Answer (score 2):

As per the **Puranic legend** the name of such a mystical horse was : ***Uchchaihshravas***

> The legend states that the first horse emerged from the depth of the
>   ocean during the churning of the oceans. It was a horse with white
>   color and had two wings. It was known by the name of Uchchaihshravas.
>   The legend continues that Indra, king of the devas, took away the
>   mythical horse to his celestial abode, the svarga (heaven).
>   Subsequently, Indra severed the wings of the horse and presented the
>   same to the mankind. The wings were severed to ensure that the horse
>   would remain on the earth (prithvi) and not fly back to Indra’s
>   svarga.

**Other Legends and textual references**

> The Mahabharata mentions that Uchchaihshravas rose from the Samudra
>   manthan ("churning of the milk ocean") and Indra - the god-king of
>   heaven seized it and made it his vehicle (vahana). He rose from the
>   ocean along with other treasures like goddess Lakshmi - the goddess of
>   fortune, taken by god Vishnu as his consort and the amrita - the
>   elixir of life.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashva) The legend of Uchchaihshravas, rising from the milk
>   ocean also appears in the Vishnu Purana, the Ramayana, the Matsya
>   Purana, the Vayu Purana etc. While various scriptures give different
>   lists of treasures (ratnas) of those appeared from the churning of the
>   milk ocean, most of them agree that Uchchaihshravas was one of them.

You can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uchchaihshravas)

Reference: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashva)